# Numpy matrix multiply different columns

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a quick simple way to multiply multiple columns from a numpy matrix? I'm using the code I show bellow but I was wondering if numpy offers a direct method.

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
temp = np.ones(3)
for ind in [0,3]:
    temp *= x[:,ind]
print(temp)

array([  4.,  40., 108.])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy` indexing and [`numpy.prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html).  `idx` can be any number of columns from your `array`:

```
>>> idx = [0, 3]
>>> np.prod(x[:, idx], axis=1)
```

```
array([  4,  40, 108])
```

---

Also equivalent:

```
x[:, idx].prod(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the columns since `numpy` multiplication is element-wise:

```
x[:, 0] * x[:, 3]
```

returns

```
array([  4,  40, 108])
```